# dispatch_semaphore_signal won't call PHImageManager requestImageDataForAsset called

Tags: swift, block, grand-central-dispatch

Here is my code, my question is that I want to wait the result after a async call. so I try to use semaphore, but the `dispatch_semaphore_signal` never be called, so there was a dead lock. I don't know how to resolve this problem. Can someone tell me what happened, thanks a lot

```
extension PHAsset{

func getAVAssetRepresent() -> AVURLAsset?{

    var asset:AVURLAsset?

    let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)

    let  queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)

    dispatch_async(queue) { () -> Void in

        switch self.mediaType{

        case .Image:
           PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageDataForAsset(self, options: nil) { (_, _, _, info) -> Void in
                if let _ = info , let url = info!["PHImageFileURLKey"] as? NSURL{
                    asset = AVURLAsset(URL: url)
                }
                dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
            }

        default :
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
        }

    }
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    return asset
}
```

Comment: Your semaphore usage is correct-- and according to the PHImageManager class reference, the block should enter, even in the event of a error/failure.  Are you sure you are waiting enough time before deciding that it deadlocks?  Have you tried putting a breakpoint inside of your `requestImageDataForAsset` completion block, to see if you ever enter there?

Comment: I think I have waited enough time but it never enter `requestImageDataForAsset` completion block, if there were no semaphore exist, the completion block will be called

Answer (score 0):

So after looking at your code a little more, I think your code may be contradicting.

You created a semaphore to ensure that your `requestImageDataForAsset` finishes execution before you continue.  This suggests that you would like your request to execute **synchronously**, and you don't want anything to happen until the request finishes.

However, you also dispatch your `requestImageDataForAsset` asynchronously, on a global concurrent dispatch queue.  Doing this would suggest that you want your request to happen **asynchronously** in the background

So I believe that if you want your request to happen **synchronously**, you should simply remove your `dispatch_async(queue)...` call.
If you would like your request to happen **asynchronously**, you should remove the `dispatch_semaphore`.

**However**, If you want to keep the code as you have it now, you will need to churn the runloop to continue execution (specifically in this situation, of your request that you dispatched asynchronously)

Something like this: (Pardon the Objective-C, I unfortunately am not confident in swift)

```
while (dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW))
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                                 beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10]];
```